# How can I unlock a password locked rar file without knowing the password?

Tags: password, rar

I have .rar file that is password protected, but I accidentally have forgotten the password. The file extremely important to me.

How can I get my file back? In windows, there was many programs that could remove the password of such a file. Is there one for Ubuntu?

Comment: use john: 
1. rar2john gloom.rar  > hash.txt 
2. john --format=rar5 hash.txt

Answer (score 14):

Two more options are:

- [RarCrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/)
- [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)

I have a archive to recover and currently running the first software. With second option - still haven't found a way to do it :/

Comment: Added [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202314/can-i-use-john-the-ripper-to-recover-password-in-rar-archive) about JTR software.

Answer (score 2):

frcackzip is also one of the password cracker. It can do bruteforce attack also. 
sudo apt-get install fcrackzip

can install that.

usage: `fcrackzip -u -c aA1 -l 4-6 secret.zip`

- The -c option lets you select the characterset, 'a' here means lower-case alphabets(small letters).
- The -p option lets you select an initial string to start brute-force attack.
- If you run fcrackzip without the -u option then it will throw a lot of possible passwords. When used with -u, it will try to decompress the file with those possible passwords, thus letting you know the exact one.
- aA1 are indicating that smallcase, uppercase & numbers will include in search.
- If you'd lile to include sepcial char also then you can go for ! .I mean it will be now `aA1!`
- -l stands for length , 4-6 letters.

Comment: What about .rar files?

Comment: The OP specifically mention RAR, not ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

I would say find some of those programs and run them under Wine. I'm not sure if you've ever tried this process before, but it takes a VERY long time to complete. I wish you luck in recovering those files! I know that pain...It's almost tragic :(

Answer (score 1):

cRARk has a linux client - I've never had the patience to run it, but you might have some luck.